# How to create/insert WMI object?

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

I'm doing a software that manages the Windows power plans in C#, and to get the Power Plans and set it's settings is easy by the ManagementObjet. But I want to create a new Power Plan, in other words, create a new WMI object, and I don't know how to do that.

Do any one knows how to create it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in WMI.  You can use the Win32 APIs for Power Scheme Management as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372711.aspx) to create your plan, and then monitor/manage it using WMI.

> To create a power scheme, you need to
>   first duplicate an existing scheme by
>   using the PowerDuplicateScheme
>   function, specifying the GUID of the
>   scheme you wish to base your new
>   scheme upon. You should copy one of
>   the built-in schemes and modify the
>   power settings to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's working... follow bellow how I done it:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


[DllImport("powrprof.dll", EntryPoint = "PowerDuplicateScheme", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern UInt32 PowerDuplicateScheme(IntPtr RootPowerKey, ref Guid SrcSchemeGuid, ref IntPtr DstSchemeGuid);


public static Guid createNewPowerPlan()
{
    Guid result = new Guid();
    IntPtr RetrPointer = IntPtr.Zero;

    // Attempt to duplicate the 'Balanced' Power Scheme.
    NativeMethods.PowerDuplicateScheme(IntPtr.Zero, ref VISA_PM_BASIC_SCHEMES.BALANCED, ref RetrPointer);

    if (RetrPointer != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        // Function returns a pointer-to-memory, marshal back to our Guid variable.
        result = (Guid)Marshal.PtrToStructure(RetrPointer, typeof(Guid));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Thanks for your help